# Is there a way to change the language detection per project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I using Visual Studio Code to work on multiple projects (and *languages*). Some projects are based on Django, others are on React (JS).

Is there a way to set up Visual Studio Code associate specific file extensions with a given language on a per project basis?

Typically, I want to associate .html files with 'Django templates' and .js files with 'Javascript' when working on project A.
reciprocally, I want to associate .html files with 'HTML' and .js files with 'Javascript React' when working on project B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.vscode/settings.json` in each project directory and put the setting `files.associations` with the correct associations in it.

Comment: You can read the [official documentation for files associations here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) for same examples.